# Linq for objects

Tags: linq, c#-4.0, nhibernate

I have:

```
   public class Basket
{
    public int BasketId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<BasketItem> BasketItems {get; set;}

}


public class BasketItem
{
    public int BasketItemId { get; set;}
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public int BasketId { get; set;}
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public virtual Product product { get; set;}
}

public class Product
{
    public int ProductId { get; set;}
    public string ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

Can anyone know how to query in linq to retrieve BasketList which includes basketItems list and prodcut ?

Sorry: The question had confused. I'm trying retrieve basketList with this:

```
(from b in Baskets
      join bi in BasketItems on b.Id equals bi.BasketId
      join pp in Products on bi.ProductId equals pp.Id
      where b.Id == 10001
      select b).ToList()
```

Product is not included in basketItems with above linq query.  I've updated the question.

Comment: That's a strange starting point. You don't have a complex object here, you have three unrelated objects with primitive members. I would expect Basket to have an IEnumerable<BasketItem> property, and BasketItem to have an instance of Product. Then you can take an instance of Basket and write some LINQ to traverse and project the object graph.

Answer (score 0):

You've set up your objects like a relational database with ProductId and BasketId as foreign keys onto a BasketItem "table".  It is better to embed your "sub" classes into your container class.  That makes using Linq to query much easier.

Try:

```
public class BasketItem
    {
        public int BasketItemId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public Basket Basket { get; set; }
        public Product Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class Basket
    {
        public int BasketId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Product
    {
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
    }

    private void SetupAndQuery()
    {
        #region setup data objects

        Product product01 = new Product {ProductName = "Whizzo", ProductId = 12345};
        Basket basket01 = new Basket {Name = "Johns Basket", BasketId = 34535987};

        Product product02 = new Product { ProductName = "Blammo", ProductId = 54321 };
        Basket basket02 = new Basket { Name = "Susans Basket", BasketId = 23546758 };

        List<BasketItem> basketItems = new List<BasketItem>();

        BasketItem basketItem01 = new BasketItem();
        basketItem01.BasketItemId = 12365;
        basketItem01.Name = "Erm";
        basketItem01.Basket = basket01;
        basketItem01.Product = product01;

        basketItems.Add(basketItem01);

        BasketItem basketItem02 = new BasketItem();
        basketItem02.BasketItemId = 15478;
        basketItem02.Name = "What";
        basketItem02.Basket = basket02;
        basketItem02.Product = product02;

        basketItems.Add(basketItem02);

        #endregion

        #region Query

        //The 2 code blocks below do the same thing

        //Foreach/If version of the Query
        foreach (BasketItem item in basketItems)
        {
            if (item.Product.ProductId == 54321)
            {
                //Do stuff here
            }
        }

        //LINQ version of the Query
        foreach (BasketItem item in basketItems.Where(item => item.Product.ProductId == 54321))
        {
            //Do stuff here
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

You may want to change what types go inside other types.  I suggest Basket at the top and a Product list inside that.  BasketItem looks unnecessary.

Comment: appreciated your answer. I think I have confused you. Hope updated question is more make sense.